# How to efficiently bind C-style function (for Mono) to C++ style class methods

Tags: c#, c++, mono

I'm using Mono to bind C# code to C++. After setting up Mono domain etc. you bind functions accordingly:

C++ side:

```
mono_add_internal_call("Camera::SetPerspectiveVerticalFOV", Camera_SetPerspectiveVerticalFOV);

float Camera_SetPerspectiveVerticalFOV(Camera *camera, float verticalFov)
{
    camera->SetPerspectiveVerticalFOV(verticalFov);
}
```

C# side:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
public static extern void SetPerspectiveVerticalFOV_Engine(IntPtr cameraObject, float verticalFov);
```

Now, it is all working to bind the way I'm doing. That is, creating a wrapper class on the C++ side to call a class method on the object in the function parameters (Camera* camera).
However, it is incredibly tedious to create a function wrapper (and long function names) for every single Constructor/Getter/Setter just to be able to call the C++-side's class method.

Is there a way to call a C++ function by putting the class object as a function parameter such as:

```
Foo myFooObject;
Foo::SetBar( &myFooObject, parameter1, parameter2)
```

Instead of:

```
Foo myFooObject;
myFooObjcect.SetBar( paramter1, parameter2);
```

Since then I could just use some preprocessor magic to solve this easier.

Perhaps it's a simple answer, but I struggle to find an answer to it!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is [std::invoke](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) what you're looking for? That would allow you to write `std::invoke(&Foo::SetBar, myFooObject, parameter1, parameter2);`

Comment: Yes, that is excatly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Botje suggested, `std::invoke` is what I was looking for.